# Emit en Angular con observables no funciona

Tags: angular, ionic, observable

tengo el típico menú hamburguesa en ionic, el cual funciona bien en todas las paginas, en todos esta visible el icono y funciona, el tema es que tengo una pagina que es el login que lo quiero ocultar.
Para eso hice un servicio, con un observable, y en el componente del menú me subscribo a esta.
Entonces en la pagina del del login hago:

```
 this.menuLateralService.estaVisible$.emit(false);
```

Con esto el menu se oculta bien en la pantalla de login. Luego aprieto en botón login y va a un listado de productos, y ejecuto también en el ngOnInit:

```
this.menuLateralService.estaVisible$.emit(true);
```

La idea es mostrar el menú, pero el tema es que el emit no se ejecuta, no se por que, pero al no ejecutarse, el menú que esta subscripto a estaVisible$ obviamente no se muestra.

Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando? Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Puedes compartir tu repo o muestra de tu cádigo para revisarlo? Igual crea un ejemplo en https://stackblitz.com/ para verlo allí

Comment: Perdón, pero tenia errores de conceptos, debería usar MenuController para Activar o desactivar el menú, entonces saque todo lo que es observables, y lo que hago con el menuctrl. 
Resumiendo, con estas lineas en la pagina de login, el menu deja de andar
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menu.enable(false);     
   }
No se que pasa

Comment: Se me ocurren varías razones por las que no te funcione:

¿ Puedes mostrar el .subscribe a estaVisible$ ? 
¿ Y qué tipo de Observable es ? 
¿ dónde tienes el `providers: MenuLateralService` ?

Comment: AL final, como no estaba muy avanzado el proyecro, cree uno nuevo y antes actualice ionic, al hacerlo todo funciono bien,
la verdad no se que habrá sido, gracias igualmente